# Proper notation

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, notation

I'm submitting a paper (PCCP, not a math journal) and a reviewer asked me write the expression for the marginal distribution.

I'd like to write it for an arbitrary number of dimensions, instead of the usual two. Right now I have:

$\mathcal{P}(\vartheta_{i}\lvert Z) = \int_{\vartheta_{j \neq i}}\mathcal{P}(\vartheta\lvert Z)d\vartheta_{j\neq i}$

But the $i$ and $j$ indicees are weird. I think I'm abusing notation. How can I fix this to be clear that you integrate over all indices that whose parameter's you don't want?

(note, to keep it consistent with my paper I'm integrating the posterior distribution whose marginal distributions I'm interested in)

Comment: For a vector $\mathbf{x}$ I think $\mathbf{x}_{-i}$ is reasonably popular notation for leaving out the $i$th element, so something like $d\mathbf{x}_{-i}$ for the volume element maybe? I mean your expression makes sense to me, see what previously published articles in this journal have used?

Comment: I agree with @Nadiels. In functional analysis, I have also seen the notation $\mathrm d\hat x_i$ to indicated everything but $\mathrm dx_i$. I also find the integral subscript confusing, usually it's $\mathbb R^{n - 1}$.

Comment: @rubik so how would you write this integral then (I've already re-submitted so it's merely for recrod). To be clear what I'm trying to say is that I'm integrating over all dimension that are not included in i (which can be more than one dimension)

Comment: Well usually densities are defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so all dimensions are the same. If you remove the one that refers to the $i$-th component it's just $\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$, or are you referring to something else entirely? If I understood correctly, I would write it as
$$\mathcal{P}(\vartheta_{i}\lvert Z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}}\mathcal{P}(\vartheta\lvert Z)\mathrm d\vartheta_{-i}$$
*and* specify that $\mathrm d\vartheta_{-i} = \mathrm d\vartheta_1 \cdots \mathrm d\vartheta_{i - 1}\mathrm d\vartheta_{i + 1}\cdots \mathrm d\vartheta_n$, or any other explanation you see fit.